# Detox - cannot use the scroll action on a ScrollView element

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

Unfortunately I can't understand why `scroll` and `scrollTo` actions don't work.

This is very strange because the `swipe` action works fine for the **same element**.

Of course, the `ScrollView` element **exists** and is **visible**.

**Detox version:** `16.9.2`

**Action:**

```
await element(by.id('some')).scrollTo('bottom');
```

**Element:**

```
<ScrollView testID="some">
```

**Error message:**

```
Cannot find UI element.
    Exception with Action: {
      "Action Name":  "Scroll To Bottom content edge",
...

Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description":  "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
        "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code":  "0",
        "File Name":  "GREYElementInteraction.m",
        "Function Name":  "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
        "Line":  "124"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 4):

try this to see if it works for you:

```
await waitFor(element.by(id('element_you_looking_for_at_the_bottom')))
   .toBeVisible()
   .whileElement(by.id('some')) // where some is your ScrollView testID
   .scroll(50, 'down')
```

I had the same problem as you are, so had to use this approach instead

Comment: what is `awaitFor`?
you have a syntax error.
correct syntax is: 
`await waitFor(element(by.id('elementTestId'))).toBeVisible().whileElement(by.id('scrollViewTestId')).scroll(100, 'down')`